# region based environment based dynamic vars file loading in ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

i want to load specific var files in ansible based on region and environment type.
I have a playbook which creates several ec2 instances in at a go with following kind of configuration -

```
---
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: true
  any_errors_fatal: true
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/ec2.yml

  roles:
    - role-for-instance-1-creation
    - role-for-instance-1-creation
```

but the problem is.. depending on the user requirement, it may create the instances in EU region once, in US region some other time. ec2.yml contains ec2 role related vars which may vary depending on the region , also depending on the enviroment, is it prod or is it testing. but i could not find a way.

I need some kind of structure.. where suppose user provided extra vars while running the playbook like `--extra-vars "environment=prod location=EU"`
and the playbook will create the ec2 instnaces in the specfic region reading specific ec2.yml file like `ec2_prod_EU.yml` or like

```
ec2_testing_US.yml
```

or in better way that vars files will be loaded from specific directory

```
group_vars/prod/ec2-EU.yml
group_vars/testing/ec2-US.yml
```

how can i do that.. include_vars is an option but is there any better way to acheive it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you creating specific, named hosts, or are you creating 30 of these, 20 of those, and 42 of that over there?

Comment: Not named hosts.. only several servers over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it in the following way-
conditionally added vars file on the roles and the condition parameters i have passed while executing the playbook -

```
- name: dynamic ec2 yml load
  include_vars:
        file: group_vars/test/ec2_us_test_session_host_1.yml
  when: environment_use == 'test' and location == 'us'
  tags:
          - ec2-creation
```

and while calling the playbook -

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --extra-vars "source_ami=${Source_AMI} Description_new_hosts=${description} environment_use=${environment_use} location=${location} availability_zone=${AZ} subnet=${subnet}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I put all that info in `group_vars/all`, so `localhost` would automatically have the variables it needs.  So the file `group_vars/all/infrastructure.yml` might look like this:

```
environments:
- environment: prod
  region: us-east1
  servers:
  - type: app
    count: 50
    instance_type: m4.xlarge
  - type: data
    count: 15
    instance_type: m4.xlarge
- environment: test
  region: us-west2
  servers:
  - type: app
    count: 5
    instance_type: m4.xlarge
  - type: data
    count: 3
    instance_type: m4.xlarge
```

Now, your `ec2` call has to cycle through all that.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Provision a set of instances
    ec2:
        instance_type: "{{ item.1.instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ image }}"
        region: "{{ item.0.region }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnets[item.0.env] }}"
        tenancy: "{{ tenancy }}"
        group_id: "{{ group_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
        wait: true
        instance_tags:
           Type: "{{ item.1.type }}"
           Env: "{{ item.0.env }}"
        count_tag:
           Type: "{{ item.1.type }}"
           Env: "{{ item.0.env }}"
        exact_count: "{{ item.1.count }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ environments }}"
      - servers
```

There's some other stuff in there you'll need to set.  I do not know your environment, but this is how I built the EC2 servers for the ACA (a.k.a., Obamacare).

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but im curious how you would define at runtime whether the playbook is running for prod or not..i am looking for something where i can mention these things like prod or test ,which region the playbook needs to run for and depending on my runtime inputs( may be extra_vars) it will pick up specific key values from all.yml

Comment: Actually, we had completely separate environments for prod, test, and dev.  There were even multiple prod environments we called "shards."   I modified the ACA format for your situation.  Where I put `environments` above, we had `zones`, and different types of servers in differenct zones -- presentation, application, and data.  As a general safety rule, always separate production out into a different inventory.

Comment: i am using a work around like .. i am passing environment=test in extra vars when playbook executes and in the specific ec2 task i am trying use condition var file inclusion in a way   include_vars:
    file: ec2_EU.yml
- name: Launch ec2
  ec2:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    group: "{{ security_group }}"

but it is not including the var file i guess as it is throwing undefined security group though there is a key by the name security group in the ec2_EU yml.. can you suggest what i am doing wrong.. basically if this way var files get loaded.. it will solve my problem

Comment: Better would be to separate the inventories and pass the inventory in with `-i`.